# Is it possible to access the Object Array using its reference?

Tags: java

I have a method that returns the reference to the array of object, and I need to get the count of the items in the array. Is it possible ?
The snippt of the method is as follow:

```
public Object getAllDChannelId()
{
  Object[] items = getAllItems();
  Object[] ids = new Object[items.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    ids[i] = items[i].getId();
  return ids;
}
```

Now I am trying to get the count of items returend through getAllDChannelId(). How to get that ?

edit: I don't want(actually can not) change the signature of the method getAllDChannelId().

Comment: Why isn't the return type `Object[]` instead?

Comment: Does it really compile???

Comment: @asifsid88 : yes its compiled perfectly.

Comment: @BheshGurung: some places i need reference only, so the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enter code hereChange the return type of the function

```
public Object[] getAllDChannelId()
{
  Object[] items = getAllItems();
  Object[] ids = new Object[items.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    ids[i] = items[i].getId();
  return ids;
}
```

At the calling environment

```
Object[] returnObj = getAllDChannelId();
System.out.println("Length: "+returnObj.length);
```

**Updated**
If for some cases you just need reference then do this when you need array of objects

```
Object[] returnObj = (Object[])getAllDChannelId();
System.out.println("Length: "+returnObj.length);
```

Comment: Sorry @asifsid88, but I can not change the signature of getAllDChannelId(). Any other way please.

Answer (score 4):

Cast the return `Object` to `Object[]` and use it.

```
Object[] objs = (Object[]) getAllDChannelId();
```

Comment: Let me also mention that, I could not change the signature of the method  getAllDChannelId() ,

Comment: `Object[] objs = (Object[])getAllDChannelId();`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to one thing Cast `Object` into `Object[]` in return type of method. It will work.